# Persisting user-defined groupings of members in SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to allow users to specify their own dynamic grouping of members.  In the AdventureWorks tutorial, that would mean a user could define "Product Group 1" as Accessories and Clothing, and "Product Group 2" as Accessories and Bikes." I could have an

I can get results like that by defining members as part of the MDX query:

```
with 
  member [Product].[Category].[Product Group 1] as 
    aggregate({[Product].[Category].[Accessories], [Product].[Category].[Clothing]})
  member [Product].[Category].[Product Group 2] as 
    aggregate({[Product].[Category].[Accessories], [Product].[Category].[Bikes]})    
select  [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] on 0,
   {[Product].[Category].[Product Group 1], [Product].[Category].[Product Group 2] } on 1
from [Analysis Services Tutorial]
```

My question is: is there any way I could save these product groups as part of the cube, so you could just reference `{[Product].[CustomGroups]}` rather than having to include `with member group1 as ... member group2 as ..` on the query?

Sure, I could incorporate them into the dimensional model itself, which is *almost* what I want, but I'd like changes to take effect without refreshing the cube.

Comment: how can they become part of the cube but you'd "like changes to take effect without refreshing the cube." ? I would think that you can just create two custom members `[Product Group 1]` and `[Product Group 2]` and a custom set `[mySetofProdGroups]` in the cube-script?

Comment: @whytheq do you mean something like `create member [product group 1] as ... ; create set [mySetOfProdGroups] as {[product group 1], ...} `?

Comment: exactly - but I assumed you'd already tried that: so maybe just misinterpreting the Queation.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to SSAS and not fluent in all the concepts yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. Inside the cube-script you should be able to:

1.
`CREATE` the custom members that you mentioned:

```
create member [product group 1] as ...
create member [product group 2] as ...
```

2.
`CREATE` the custom set that you mentioned:

```
create set [productSet] as ...{[product group 1],[product group 2]}
```

Exact syntax for the above will be on `MSDN`